# entity-framework read requests logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm currently writing an audit trail. So far so good.
Now i've stumbled upon the process of registering read/select requests from certain Controller/Actions to our database (entity-framework) on specific tables. For example a Linq Select query.

How can i monitor a request to the database, looking for something similiar to the SavingChanges event.

I have been working with ObjectMaterialized but its not what im looking for, also database triggers are no option atm.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't implement this at the database level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to write your own Entity Framework provider-wrapper, which will log all information you need. For example there is: [Tracing and Caching Provider Wrappers for Entity Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32)

Answer (score 0):

With @Maess. Just create a data access class that hands off auditing to an auditing class. Something like:

```
class DataAccess
{
    void UpdateEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        _entityAudit.UpdateAudit(entity, _currentUser);

        // your update logic
        var existing = _dataSet.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ID == entity.ID);
        ...
    }
}
```